# Vertically center text in an absolutely centered sphere

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

I have tried a couple of techniques, but so far nothing works to center text in an absolutely centered sphere. The size of the sphere is known, but not the length of the text. Here is an example that is lacking vertical alignment:

http://jsfiddle.net/eevw3oes/

css:

```
div
{
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It absolutely can be done with css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox to the rescue: http://jsfiddle.net/eevw3oes/2/

```
div {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    …
}
```

This can also be accomplished by adding more DOM and using traditional css. I see you're trying to use `vertical-align: middle`, but that doesn't work on block elements (only with inline-block and table-cell).

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox would work, and so will transforms:

```
<div class=circle style="left: 50px;">
    <div class=text>
    I'd like to be centered.
    </div>
</div>

<div class=circle style="left: 200px;">
    <div class=text>
    I would like also like to be centerd. Even though I have long text. I would like to be centerd horizontally and vertically. Is that possible. Oh I wish it would work.
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added inner `<div>` elements for the text.  The CSS:

```
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}

div.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
}
```

[CodePen.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/qneks)

Comment: Pretty awesome! If I could vote 2 answers as the solution, I would vote this one too.

Comment: This is good for a lot of situations where flexbox is not appropriate; however, this is more expensive to render. Also, if you try to do css animations/transitions, `transform` accepts multiple functions (scale, translate, etc), and their order matters, so manipulating them is difficult.

Comment: @jacob It's expensive I guess, but how many elements are you going to be vertically centering? If it's 300 or 5000 or whatever, then yes the performance is worth thinking about. I suspect that for a lot of designs it's one or two elements.

Comment: I suspect that as well. Just pointing out the perf implications. Also, combining hardware-accelerated props with absolute/fixed positioning can cause a baffling rendering bug in webkit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could add `line-height` with the same value as `width`

```
line-height: 100px;
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eevw3oes/1/)

Someone had already a similar problem on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css).

Comment: The problem with that solution is that you can only fit one row of text

Comment: the text does not wrap in that fiddle. i want the text to wrap.